# Xamarin - Clicking CardView in a fragment to load another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-cardview

I have a RecycledView fragment that has CardView items. Everytime the user clicks on one of the cards, it should load another fragment, corresponding to the position of the card. I have looked everywhere for a solution about this, but since you can write the RecycledView logic in a different way, the solutions I've found don't work on me.

How the layout looks:
[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Json;
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Views.Animations;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Homecheck.Adapters;
using Homecheck.Models;

namespace *********.Fragments {
    public class Dashboard : GridLayoutBase {
        private ISharedPreferences pref;
        private SessionManager session;
        private string cookie;
        private DeviceModel deviceModel;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        private List<ItemData> itemData;
        private const string URL_DASHBOARD = "http://10.1.1.20/appapi/getdashboard";

        public async override void OnStart() {
            base.OnStart();

            session = new SessionManager();
            pref = Activity.GetSharedPreferences("UserSession", FileCreationMode.Private);
            cookie = pref.GetString("PHPSESSID", string.Empty);
            var jsonFetcher = new JsonFetcher();
            JsonValue jsonDashboard = await jsonFetcher.FetchDataWithCookieAsync(URL_DASHBOARD, cookie);
            deviceModel = new DeviceModel();
            deviceModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceModel>(jsonDashboard);

            DisplaySensorStates();

            DisplayLastPhoto();

            adapter = new ViewAdapter(itemData);

            new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
                Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                    recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
                });
            })).Start();
        }

        // Shows sensor states
        public void DisplaySensorStates() {
            itemData = new List<ItemData>();

            foreach (var sensor in deviceModel.Sensors) {
                itemData.Add(new ItemData() {
                    image = Resource.Drawable.smoke_red,
                    title = sensor.Name.First().ToString().ToUpper() + sensor.Name.Substring(1).ToLower() + " sensor",
                });
            }
        }

        // Shows the last camera photo
        public async void DisplayLastPhoto() {
            if (deviceModel.Error == "true" && deviceModel.ErrorType == "noPhoto") {
                //TODO: Show a "No photo" picture
            } else {
                string url = deviceModel.LastPhotoLink;
                Bitmap imageBitmap = await new ImageDownloader().GetImageBitmapFromUrlAsync(url, Activity, lastPhoto.Width, lastPhoto.Height);
                lastPhoto.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                imageBitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Dashboard, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.dashboard_recycler_view);
            layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Activity, 3);

            recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;

            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.AddItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(8));

            return view;
        }

        public class ViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter {
            private List<ItemData> itemData;
            private ImageView imageId;
            private TextView sensorStatus;

            public ViewAdapter(List<ItemData> itemData) {
                this.itemData = itemData;
            }

            public class ItemView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                public View mainView { get; set; }

                public ImageView image { get; set; }

                public TextView status { get; set; }

                public ItemView(View view) : base(view) {
                    mainView = view;
                }
            }

            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.DashboardItems, null);
                CardView cardView = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.dashboard_card_view);
                imageId = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.sensor_image);
                sensorStatus = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sensor_status);

                var viewHolder = new ItemView(itemLayoutView) { image = imageId, status = sensorStatus };

                return viewHolder;
            }

            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
                ItemView itemHolder = viewHolder as ItemView;

                itemHolder.image.SetImageResource(itemData[position].image);
                itemHolder.status.Text = itemData[position].title;
            }

            public override int ItemCount {
                get { return itemData.Count; }
            }
        }

        public class ItemData {
            public int image { get; set; }

            public string title { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is at least the third time you ask the same question

Comment: Please stop deleting and reposting the same question. Instead -  please [edit] your question to include any additional information or to make corrections.